# JAX-WS adding addressing for iBM websphere, IBM web services client

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am running code on websphere and using soap 2.12-2.2?.  And the RAD tools to generate the IBM JAX-WS web-services client code.  I can connect out to the server in question but the web services requires addressing to be on.  If I use a http-client code and soap ui, I can get this request to work and I see the particular SOAP action addressing header.  But I can't find a way to add this for the jax-ws code.  I mention websphere ibm because I wonder if it is a bug internal to that code.  Under the covers, the library is org.apache.axis2 for jax-ws.  Here is all the code I tried.

Expected request:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ser="http://schemas.schedulenow.com/paramedclients/services" xmlns:data="http://schemas.schedulenow.com/paramedclients/data" xmlns:arr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
   <soap:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
  <wsa:Action soap:mustUnderstand="1">http://sion</wsa:Action><wsa:To soap:mustUnderstand="1">...</wsa:To></soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <ser:Initialize>
```

This contains a valid request when I take the raw string and hit the server.  When I use jax-ws ibm cod.e the 'wsa:Action' is missing.

The WSDL has this:

But for some reason, the client just won't add that required header. I tried the following.

```
            SSLSocketFactory sslFactory = GenerateSocketAndTrustManager.createSSLFactory();

            _desc.getDispatch().getRequestContext().put("com.ibm.ws.wsaddressingAndDependentsDisabled", false); 
            _desc.getDispatch().getRequestContext().put("com.ibm.ws.wsaddressingAndDependentsDisabled", false); 
            _desc.getDispatch().getRequestContext().put("com.ibm.ws.wsaddressing.disabled", false); 
            _desc.getDispatch().getRequestContext().put("com.ibm.ws.wsaddressing.wsdl.UsingAddressing", true);



@Addressing(enabled=true, required=true)
@WebServiceClient(name = "ScheduleService", targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/", wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/ScheduleService_1.wsdl")



            AddressingFeature feat = new AddressingFeature(true, false);            
            _service.getWSHttpBindingScheduleService(feat);
```

Comment: Hi. I believe you already checked https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24965/wsaddressing.htm#WSADV676 ? Especially the part of adding the feature to the getPort() part is not reflected in what you've tried so far?!

Comment: Yep, with a mountain documentation.  That looks like the solution.  Can you post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24965/wsaddressing.htm#WSADV676), the way to go would be to add the `AddressingFeature` where you create your Port (example taken from Oracle docs):

```
HelloWorld port = service.getHelloWorldPort(
    new AddressingFeature(true, true));
```